# Can you have a rectangle with height=0?

Tags: geometry

Is it possible to have a rectangle with the height or width equal to 0?

Comment: I'd just imagine two lines overlapping.

Comment: Why do you want such a rectangle?  Some theorems about "rectangles" will fail for those.  But in other cases (for example defining a Riemann sum graphically) you may want to allow "rectangle" to include these.

Comment: That is not a rectangle.

Comment: The [Wikipedia page on degeneracy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degeneracy_(mathematics)) might be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can consider it a "degenerate rectangle," yes.

The same could be used for a "degenerate triangle" formed by three collinear points.

I don't think people do this really, but you could probably extend this and consider a square with an extra point added in one of its edges as a degenerate pentagon, etc. We typically opt for the simplest descriptor, but on occasion something like this is handy.

Comment: *"I don't think people do this really, but you could probably extend this and consider a square with an extra point added in one of its edges as a degenerate pentagon, etc."* I do this. Really. (And I'm a people!) ;)  This level of flexibility is vital for providing as-general-as-possible geometric formulas and relations. Often, you'll see the term "non-degenerate" used to indicate that that an author needs to avoid full generality because something might break (for instance, if a formula required dividing by the area of the triangle determined by two adjacent sides of a pentagon).

Comment: @Blue Yes, after reading further into the wiki degeneracy article, I noticed that something like this was [mentioned in there](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degeneracy_(mathematics)#Convex_polygon). It makes lot of mathematical sense, I just wasn't sure it happened. Thanks for the testimonial!